# 'Base forbidden. Need user.' error when trying to create a QBCustomObject

Tags: android, quickblox

When I try to save `QBCustomObject`, response from server sometimes it says

> Base forbidden. Need User.

Before saving, I checked `QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn()` and it returns true.

This error happens for both:

- just after logging in
- and, for example, 10 minutes afterwards

Disappears after re-launching the app and signing in process.

```
HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
fields.put("name", name);
fields.put("User ID", currentUser.getId());

QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject();
qbCustomObject.setUserId(currentUser.getId());
qbCustomObject.setClassName("Group");
qbCustomObject.setFields(fields);

QBCustomObjects.createObject(qbCustomObject, new QBCallbackImpl() {...});
```

Here are the chain of actions which leads to creating `QBCustomObject`:

```
QBAuth.createSession() -> QBUsers.signIn() -> QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser()
```

Why does this error happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like I've found the bug. I didn't used the `QBUser` object I got from `.signIn()` response. Here is what I mean:

```
QBUsers.signIn(user, new QBCallbackImpl() {
     @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            QBUser signedInUser = (((QBUserResult) result).getUser());
            signedInUser.setPassword(password);
            //...
            loginToChat(signedInUser);
            //...
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Chat login and login to Application - they are different logins.

In order to create any object in QuickBlox (except a chat message) - you must act on the user's behalf

More info here how to create a record http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android#Create_record_using_Android_SDK

There you will find a link how to login a user to application  http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization

Comment: Well, I've signed in the user before start creating new QBCustomObject. If it's not what you were talking about, then can you please tell me what particular steps should I do?

Answer (score 0):

create your session with QBUser.

ex :- QBAuth.createSession(new QBUser("user_name", ""))